# R programming: Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : NA/NaN/Inf in 'y'

Tags: r

As an input i am trying this:

```
df <- data$Sex
data$Sex <- gsub("M|F", "MF", data$Sex)
data$Length[which(is.nan(data$Length))] = NA
data$Length[which(data$Length==Inf)] = NA
data$Sex[which(is.nan(data$Sex))] = NA
data$Sex[which(data$Sex==Inf)] = NA
model4a <- lm(data$Sex ~ data$Length,na.action=na.exclude)
plot(model4a,pch=16,which=1)
cf <- round(coef(model4a), 7)
eq <- paste("Sex = ",cf[1],"+", abs(cf[2]),"* Length")
mtext(eq, 3, line=-2)
```

But i got the following error:

```
Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
NA/NaN/Inf in 'y'
In addition: Warning message:
In storage.mode(v) <- "double" : NAs introduced by coercion
```

What am i doing wrong.I saw that similar questions are already there on this site,but their solution don't help me.Any help would be appreciated!I have provided a link for the file on which i am doing the operation below:
[File](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1T48DcUCQBErna9uhSwUQSKilDq58x8TYWBdNN15FE88/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: The file in the link doesn't have column headers. The first column is obviously `Sex` but which one is `Length`? And do the others have names? Please edit the question with the output of `names(data)`. In the mean time instead of `data$Length==Inf` try `is.infinite(data$Length)`.

Comment: Both `sapply(data, function(x) any(is.nan(x)))` and `sapply(data, function(x) any(is.infinite(x)))` return all values `FALSE`.

Comment: column Sex looks like it is a string you should make it a factor and use glm with binomial family if only two categories.
Also you should use formula notation in lm/glm `glm(Sex ~ Length , data = data, family = binomial)`